# Nginx load balance with multi server and multi application instance

Tags: nginx, tornado

I use nginx to load balance my tornado app.
There are 3 instances of the same application(listen on different port) on server_A. Below are my configuration.

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        server server_A_IP:8888;
        server server_A_IP:8887;
        server server_A_IP:8886;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have another server_B, and also I start 3 instances on this server, so I add 3 lines to my config's upstream.

```
   upstream myapp1 {
    server server_A_IP:8888;
    server server_A_IP:8887;
    server server_A_IP:8886;

    server server_B_IP:8888;
    server server_B_IP:8887;
    server server_B_IP:8886;
}
```

This would be ugly if I start 10 instances on each server or add a large amount server to upstream.

Is there any proper way to to this?
What is the recommand way to load balance multi server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper way would be to use specialised tool for balancing.

Another way, quite simple, is to have domain name that points to multiple IPs and use that domain name in `server` directive.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server

> A domain name that resolves to several IP addresses defines multiple servers at once.

So you would use

```
upstream myapp1 {
    server upstream.example.net:8886;
    server upstream.example.net:8887;
    server upstream.example.net:8888;
}
```

and add IPs to DNS when needed.

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better.  What happend If DNS cache point this host to server_IP_A? Would requests also load balance to server B and C? I am not familiar with DNS, please correct me if I am woring. Thanks

Comment: @billy_lu what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear. I already know how it works after saw this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26957754/3680194. Thanks!